# Enviar formularios reactivos a api con cURL en Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, stripe

Estoy usando Stripe para los pagos de una aplicacion, pero me acabo de atorar al momento de enviar el formulario de tarjeta. Estoy usando formularios reactivos para obtener los datos y al momento de ingresar los datos y enviarlos al servicios si me devuelve los valores que ingreso

```
{"card[number]":"424242424242","card[exp_month]":"02","card[exp_year]":"22","card[cvc]":"123"}
```

pero al momento de quererlos enviar a la ruta me arroja un error. Para enviar los datos estoy usando el cURL

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens \
  -u sk_test_{KEY}: \
  -d "card[number]"=4242424242424242 \
  -d "card[exp_month]"=11 \
  -d "card[exp_year]"=2021 \
  -d "card[cvc]"=314
```

En mi componente para recuperar los datos del formulario y enviarlo al servicio lo tengo de la siguiente manera

```
cardForm = this._formBuilder.group({
  'card[number]': ['', Validators.required],
  'card[exp_month]': ['', Validators.required],
  'card[exp_year]': ['', Validators.required],
  'card[cvc]': ['', Validators.required],
});

cardSubmit(){
  console.log(this.cardForm.value);
  this._paymentsService.generateToken(this.cardForm.value).subscribe(
    response => {
      console.log(response);
    },
    error => {
      console.error(<any>error);
    }
  );
}
```

Y en mi servicio para seleccionarlo y enviarlo es de la siguiente manera

```
generateToken(card) :Observable<any>{
    let json = JSON.stringify(card);
    let params = card;
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded').set('Authorization', 'Bearer '+ this.tokenPublic);
    return this._http.post(this.tokenStripe, params, {headers:headers});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El flujo ideal es que tu servidor nunca reciba datos de la tarjeta de crédito directamente, sino a través de un token generado por Stripe. De esta forma evitas tener que certificar tu sitio con PCI-DSS.

Te recomiendo darle una mirada a Stripe [Checkout](https://stripe.com/mx/payments/checkout) o [Elements](https://stripe.com/payments/elements).

Comment: De hecho lo que hago ahorita es que envio el token a la api de laravel y ahi ya empiezo a crear el customer y luego la suscripcion... no se si esa manera este correcto

Comment: Eso suena bien, avísame si continúas teniendo problemas.